# Can I use the name of the thread as custom interrupt flag?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a program with 2 threads, t1 is timeout thread and t2 is working thread like this:

```
public class Test{
    static Thread t1,t2;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
                if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    t2.interrupt();
                    System.out.println("request timeout");
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();

        t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
                if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    t1.interrupt();
                    System.out.println("request succeed");
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

I know it is not working because Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() is false all the time and the output is

```
request timeout
request succeed
```

which I want either

```
request timeout
```

or

```
request succeed
```

only. So I need another flag to indicate if a thread is still working. But I don't want to extend the Thread class to add a custom boolean property and I found Thread has a name attribute, can I just use the name attribute as interrupt flag like this:

```
public class Test{
    static Thread t1,t2;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
                if(!Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("")){
                    t2.setName("");
                    t2.interrupt();
                    System.out.println("request timeout");
                }
            }
        },"t1");
        t1.start();

        t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
                if(!Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("")){
                    t1.setName("");
                    t1.interrupt();
                    System.out.println("request succeed");
                }
            }
        },"t2");
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

is there any problem above? for example, is there any concurrency problem in

```
t2.setName("");
t2.interrupt();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

According to the JAVA API documentation for `Thread.interrupt()`, if you call this method upon a thread which in sleep mode, the interrupt status is cleared and you will get an InterruptedException. So, in your case, when you do t2.interrupt(), Thread 2 will be interrupted from the sleep mode, an InterruptedException will be thrown by sleep method (which you can catch it and handle it). Due to the fact that interrupt status is cleared when `interrupt()` is called upon a thread which is sleeping, `Thread.isInterrupted()` will always return false.

So, in order to get the output you desire my suggestion is to put exception handling for InterruptException in both threads, and handle the messages printed accordingly.